# Is Cocos2d-x always uses OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

Can I relay on my Cocos2d-x based application game to always use OpenGL (and OpenGL ES in mobile platforms)? Since this library allows inline OpenGL calls within it's code I want to know if I can use them without worrying about portability. Is there anything else Cocos2d-x uses for rendering? Like DirectX in Windows Desktop / Phone and maybe a software renderer on devices without graphic cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocos2d-x uses OpenGL on all platforms.

Keep in mind that on Desktop OSs depending on OS, GPU and drivers the OpenGL renderer may fall back to software rendering for certain features, or not support them at all (drawing glitches or errors).

Moreover OpenGL for desktop computers and OpenGL ES for mobile devices are not fully compatible both in API and supported features.

Comment: The part about the difference between OpenGL Core and OpenGL ES I'm already familiar with from other projects, but what do you mean the GPU/Drivers fall back to software renderer? It means that my GL calls gets rendered with a software renderer instead of the GPU? If it does, that's ok for me too, I just don't want the game to crush because I use bare GL calls.

Comment: well, in particular on windows there are some terrible (integrated) graphics chips and some with terribly inefficient drivers, or both. For instance some drivers report that the graphics chip implements a certain GL feature where in fact it does not. If your app uses that feature, OpenGL will use a software rendering path for that feature, either crippling performance or causing rendering issues, or both. Older integrated Intel (notebook) graphics chips are well known for such flaky implementations.

Comment: Oh ok, I understand now. Since I'm targeting mainly mobile platforms (specifically Android, iOS and Windows Phone) I can address the issues with the desktop version later. Thanks a lot for your help!